# How to record video, audio and compress the same video using ffmpeg, so that both the task can be done in a single command line

Tags: ffmpeg, video-recording, video-compression

I am newly using "ffmpeg". I have compressed the video which is stored in the directory, then I got to know that we can do "compression and recording" both at a time using ffmpeg. I tried this by using the below command but that is not working unable to record as well. Anyone please help me out to solve. Thanks in advance.

I tried using this command "ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 10 -i desktop out.mpeg" this is giving error like- "Unknown input format: 'gdigrab' ".

I want the result which should "compress the live recording video" and store it in a folder or db.

Comment: What is your OS? Show the complete log from the ffmpeg command.

Comment: Hi @llogan, I am using Mac OS, ``` ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "0:0" out.mpg ``` from this command line I am able to record the video without frame, kindly suggest me how to record using frame and compress while recording.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by, "record using frame".

Comment: `gdigrab` is Windows only, the Mac equivalent is `avfoundation`. More information is available in [the FFmpeg screen capturing docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop).